# Reload content after JSON response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I reload or append the escape javascript file in Json format request in rails.

I am uploading the xls file, and working fine. I wanna to show the uploaded data's as uploaded . but getting json format.

please guide

Comment: Please guide us with some relevant code to adress the issue.

Comment: `def upload_csv
     # render :json => response
      respond_to do |format|
        # format.json { render json: response }
        format.js
  end
end`